# How to declare async function properly in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am implementing async functions to be shared to different module.

```
//common.js
module.exports = {
    function1: async (params) => {
    ...
     },
    function2: (params) => {
    ...
     },
}
```

In other module, how I used the function as below:

```
const common = require('./../common.js');

...
common.function1(params).then (resp => {
   ...
   common.function2(params)
})
```

I got error:

> `common.function1 is not a function`

How to declare the async function properly in module.exports. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: This looks like it should work, if you are important the correct module. You seem to think this has something to do with making the function `async`. If you remove the async function, can you import the module and call its functions?

Comment: does function2 work ok?

Comment: @Geraint Yes, I tested, normal functions are working fine, except async functions

Comment: When I replace the `...` with actual code and define `params`, this runs without errors when I test it. Voting to close. [mcve] missing.

Comment: Circular dependencies maybe? Does `common.js` require anything?